# Calculating the maximum sum possible from given constraints

Tags: c++11, subset, dynamic-programming

So, I found this question on topcoder:

> Your friend Lucas gave you a sequence S of positive integers.
>
> For a while, you two played a simple game with S: Lucas would pick a
>   number, and you had to select some elements of S such that the sum of
>   all numbers you selected is the number chosen by Lucas. For example,
>   if S={2,1,2,7} and Lucas chose the number 11, you would answer that
>   2+2+7 = 11.
>
> Lucas now wants to trick you by choosing a number X such that there
>   will be no valid answer. For example, if S={2,1,2,7}, it is not
>   possible to select elements of S that sum up to 6.
>
> You are given the int[] S. Find the smallest positive integer X that
>   cannot be obtained as the sum of some (possibly all) elements of S.
>
> Constraints:
>   - S will contain between 1 and 20 elements, inclusive.
>   - Each element of S will be between 1 and 100,000, inclusive.

But in the editorial solution it has been written:

> How about finding the smallest impossible sum? Well, we can try the
>   following naive algorithm: First try with `x = 1`, if this is not a
>   valid sum (found using the methods in the previous section), then we
>   can return `x`, else we increment `x` and try again, and again until
>   we find the smallest number that is not a valid sum.
>
> Let's find an upper bound for the number of iterations, the number of
>   values of `x` we will need to try before we find a result. First of
>   all, the maximum sum possible in this problem is 100000 * 20 (All
>   numbers are the maximum 100000), this means that 100000 * 20 + 1 will
>   not be an impossible value. We can be certain to need at most 2000001
>   steps.
>
> How good is this upper bound? If we had 100000 in each of the 20
>   numbers, 1 wouldn't be a possible sum. So we actually need one
>   iteration in that case. If we want `1` to be a possible sum, we should
>   have `1` in the initial elements. Then we need a `2` (Else we would
>   only need 2 iterations), then a `4` (`3` can be found by adding
>   `1+2`), then `8` (Numbers from `5` to `7` can be found by adding some
>   of the first 3 powers of two), then `16, 32, ...`. It turns out that
>   with the powers of 2, we can easily make inputs that require many
>   iterations. With the first 17 powers of two, we can cover up to the
>   first 262143 integer numbers. That should be a good estimation for the
>   largest number. (We cannot use `2^18` in the input, smaller than
>   100000).
>
> Up to 262143 times, we need to query if a number `x` is in the set of
>   possible sums. We can just use a boolean array here. It appears that
>   even `O(log(n))` data structures should be fast enough, however.

So how is it possible that 100000*20 will give us the maximum sum possible?. Wouldnt adding all the elements of S give us the maximum sum?.Also i cant seem to understand the entire solution at all. How the subsets are used?. Can someone please explain the entire solution to me?. Im not getting the maths behind this. I am a total newbie on dynamic programming.

Thank you and sorry if i have asked too many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Constraints: - S will contain between 1 and 20 elements, inclusive. - Each element of S will be between 1 and 100,000, inclusive."

This means S is an array of integers. This array can have from 1 to 20 elements, in this case integer numbers. These numbers go from 1 to 100.000. 
So he is making a supposition considering the largest sum he can obtain out of this array, which means 20 numbers, where the number is always 100.000

S = [100000, 100000, 100000 and so on ]